# Reposition UIButton Matrix On Rotation

Tags: objective-c, button, matrix, rotation

I have a matrix of X number of buttons added to a view controller. In portrait mode it shows the buttons in perfect order. But, with the view controller is presented, and I rotate to landscape mode the buttons are not repositioned. But, if I rotate my phone and ***then*** present the view controller it has repositioned the buttons for landscape mode.

I've been stuck with this problem for some time and don't know why the buttons will not rotate when the view controller is already presented. I hope someone can help me out here.

Philip

Here's the code for creating the buttons in the first place:

```
- (void)createButtonMatrix {   
     for (int rows = 0; rows < 11; rows++) {
                    for (int columns = 0; columns < 6; columns++) {
                        NSUInteger chapter =  columns +  rows * 6 + 1;
                        if (chapter > 50)
                            break;
                        chapterButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                        chapterButtons.frame = CGRectMake(columns * 54, rows * 38, 53, 37); // columns * X, rows * Y, width, height
                        chapterButtons.tag = chapter;
                        [chapterButtons setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", chapterButtons.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [createButtonArray addObject:chapterButtons];
                        [viewController2.view addSubview:chapterButtons];
                    }
                }
    }
```

Now reposition them when rotating:

```
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
              NSLog(@"Will rotate to portrait.");
            for (int rows = 0; rows < 11; rows++) {
                for (int columns = 0; columns < 6; columns++) {
                    NSUInteger chapter =  columns +  rows * 6 + 1;
                    if (chapter > 50)
                        break;
                    chapterButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                    chapterButtons.frame = CGRectMake(columns * 54, rows * 38, 53, 37); // columns * X, rows * Y, width, height
                    chapterButtons.tag = chapter;
                    [chapterButtons setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", chapterButtons.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }

        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
                NSLog(@"Will rotate to landscape.");
                for (int rows = 0; rows < 7; rows++) {
                    for (int columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
                        NSUInteger chapter =  columns +  rows * 9 + 1;
                        if (chapter > 50)
                            break;
                        chapterButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                        chapterButtons.frame = CGRectMake(columns * 54, rows * 38, 53, 37); // columns * X, rows * Y, width, height
                        chapterButtons.tag = chapter;
                        [chapterButtons setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", chapterButtons.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code

```
chapterButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

creates new instance of UIButton class. You have to add that object to the view to make it visible. In your code you also create too much UIButton autoreleased instances.

What would be the best to do is:

1. Create an instance variable of type NSArray that will contain all the UIButton instances
2. Create UIButton objects via `[UIButton new]` or `[[UIButton alloc] init]`
3. Add all UIButton objects into that array in the method `- (void)createButtonMatrix`
4. Add all UIButton objects to the view
5. Manage frames of the UIButton objects in method `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` via array that we created previously

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But I thought that I already added the buttons to the mutable array and then to the view. Or does it have to be NSArray? Actually, the buttons are shown in the view controller. They just won't change layout on rotation when I change the amount of rows and columns. Those numbers (rows and columns) doesn't seem to have any affect unless I rotate the device first.

Comment: @Borges as I already specified, with this line: "chapterButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];" you are creating NEW instance of UIButton, you are not reusing saved buttons from array "createButtonArray"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your code, you are recreating the buttons on orientation change but these buttons are never added to the view. This is wrong.
You should just change the positioning of each button of the `createButtonArray` (filled in `createButtonMatrix()`) : don't create buttons in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`
just extract buttons from `createButtonArray` and modify their `frame` property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to art-divin, and to Jean-Baptiste for providing the answer via email. Below is the code that repositions a button matrix on rotation. The code for creating the button matrix remains the same.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    COLUMNS = 7;
    ROWSS = 8;

    int i=0; // button count iterator
    for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWSS; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < COLUMNS; columns++) {
            NSUInteger chapter =  columns +  rows * COLUMNS + 1;
            if (chapter > 50)
                break;
            UIButton *b = (UIButton *)[call.createButtonArray objectAtIndex:i++];
            b.frame = CGRectMake(columns * WIDTH, rows * 38, HEIGHT, 37); // columns * X, rows * Y, width, height
        }
    }

    [rotateController rotateChapterButtons_Portrait];
}

else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    COLUMNS = 10;
    ROWSS = 9;
    int i=0; // button count iterator
    for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWSS; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < COLUMNS; columns++) {
            NSUInteger chapter =  columns +  rows * COLUMNS + 1;
            if (chapter > 50) // > greater than
                break;
            NSLog(@"%i:",chapter);
            UIButton *b = (UIButton *)[call.createButtonArray objectAtIndex:i++];
            b.frame = CGRectMake(columns * 48, rows * 38, 47, 37); // columns * X, rows * Y, width, height
        }
    }

    [rotateController rotateChapterButtons_Landscape];
}
```

}